# Printing from a specific index in a multidimensional array using Arrays.deepToString()

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Is there a way to print a specific value from a multidimensional array using `Arrays.deepToString()`?

For example, I'd like to print the value at the index [1,1] in a multidimensional array.

I hope it makes sense.

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][] a = {
                {10,20,30,40,50},{10,20,30,40,50}
        };

        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(a));
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(a[1][1]));
    }    
}
```

Comment: Or maybe: Can someone explain why:   

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(new Integer[]{a[1][1]}));

Works?

Comment: If you just want to print the value in the specific position in the array then isn't `System.out.println(a[1][1]);` what you want? No need for deepToString or...?

Comment: This makes no sense... By *a[1][1]* you are accessing directly the value stored there. *System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(a[1][1]))* will never compile. I think you are missing something

Comment: [`Arrays.deepToString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString(java.lang.Object[])) expect an array to create a `String`. So you can't provide an `int` value like `Arrays.deepToString(a[1][1])`, in that case, print the `int` directly like `a[1][1]`

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(a[1][1]);
```

prints:

```
20
```

Answer (score 0):

The deepToString(Object[]) in Arrays returns String representation of a Object Array.
like for:-

```
 int[][] a = {{10,20,30,40,50},{10,20,30,40,50}};

 System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(a));

 Output:- [[10, 20, 30, 40, 50], [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]] // String representation of 'a'
```

deepToString() is nothing other than this.

If want to print specific element then use coordinates of array, like

```
System.out.println(a[1][2]);  //Output:-  30
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Short Answer

Yes,
it works.
You noted this in your comment on the post.

#### Why it works

The
`Arrays.deepToString` appears to recursively expand
(and call the
`toString` method on each element of)
any array it is passed.
Your situation is the special case of
"not an array, just print the parameter".
In your example,
the second call to deepToString is unnecessary.